# Has RingCT been reviewed by the other Monero Research Lab members?

Tags: ringct, monero-research-lab

Shen Noether has created RingCT and I trust that he has done so in a safe and correct manner, but it never hurts to have more eyes on the crypto. RingCT is currently in testnet and being rigorously tested in testnet, but has Surae Noether or Sarang Noether looked over the whitepaper?

Comment: the whitepaper i am talking about is https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes absolutely. It wasn't designed in isolation, it was a group effort with members of the Core Team and the MRL involved. Since Shen did the bulk of the work, and was responsible for much of the innovative cryptography, he is the primary author on the research bulletin. You'll notice, however, that Adam Mackenzie and the Monero Core Team are also [listed as authors on the research bulletin](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf):)